# jq select or statement

Tags: jq

I have the the following input json:

```
{
  "TagList": [
    {
      "Key": "Environment",
      "Value": "foo"
    },
    {
      "Key": "ENVIRONMENT",
      "Value": "bar"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get the values of tags with the key ENVIRONMENT using `jq`:

```
jq -r '.TagList[] | select(.Key=="ENVIRONMENT") | .Value' input.json
```

But as it turned out, the key could be also `Environment`. I try get both using this command:

```
jq -r '.TagList[] | select((.Key=="ENVIRONMENT") | .Value' or .Key=="Environment" | .Value)
```

but get the following error:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ';' or ')' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.TagList[] | select((.Key=="ENVIRONMENT") | .Value
jq: 1 compile error
```

How to get both of those tags?

Comment: @eekfonky Please update your question with the output sample JSON.

Comment: learn how to create an [mcve](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I prepared that for you this time in order to show what it means. All the aws stuff was totally unnecessary on the one hand, and on the other hand was missing every useful information to reproduce the problem for others. Please review this again and post the actual command that failed. The one you posted doesn't make sense at all (because of the broken quoting)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the following command:

```
jq '.TagList[]|select(.Key=="Environment" or .Key=="ENVIRONMENT").Value'
```

Answer (score 7):

Generalizing a bit:

```
.TagList[]
| select(.Key | ascii_upcase == "ENVIRONMENT").Value
```